# Application can't find Local IIS Server

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have client-server .net application, WCF communication with IIS.
During development I encountered a strange phenomenon:
Once in a while, when I run my application without debug and press a button - it seems like the server doesn't respond to the action.
Then I turn to check the same action on debug mode, and when I try to attach the service to process in oder to debug it - I can't find the w3wp.exe process, which is surely active !
But when I open the inetmgr (IIS Manager) and press Browse to the service site - suddenly the service is found in the Attach to process list on VS, and everything continues to work - with or without debug mode - as if nothing had happened.......
Does anyone experienced something similar, or have any assumption why is this happening?
I am concerned that similar incidents can affect the stability of my system.
**Note:** Perhaps the phenomenon above occurs after I update the client service reference, but I'm not pretty sure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly if I will answer your question since it's not clear but let me put answer anyway:

I sometimes get an error in running WCF on my machine and this because I have my host running Local IIS then when I change it to IISExpress it runs without issues.

To change this, right click the project -> properties-> open web tab, locate servers and select IIS Express in dropdown. See image[image: settings]

To understand the difference between the two you can check: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-iis-express

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you response. Would you be able to tell me what's the meaning of changing my server from Local IIS to IIS Express? Does it make any substantial difference? @Bayeni

Comment: I've added a link that will explain the difference, please check the edit

Comment: Well I tryed it, and it didn't work. I was have to Browse the server from IIS to make the service work. Worse, after few clicks of the GUI button it loose the server again. I wonder, maybe this is a problem of permissions?

Comment: That also possible, that was my 2 cent :)